# Table odd even td with multicolor

Tags: html, css

[I have a table styled with CSS with even and odd](http://jsfiddle.net/UFG2n/1/).  The `td` even/odd CSS codes:

```
#table_box tr:nth-child(odd) td { background-color:#ffffff } /*odd*/
#table_box tr:nth-child(even) td { background-color:#f5f9fa } /* even*/
#table_box tr:hover td { background-color:#fffbae; } /* hovering */
```

[image]

I want to have multi even/odd color rows styles like the below image:
[image]

Can I do this with CSS? I was trying to do it but colors don't show and just even/odd styled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this fragments:
HTML changes:

```
        <tr>
                <td class="blueh2">1</td>
                <td class="blueh2">&#1777;&#1779;&#1785;&#1777;/&#1776;&#1780;/&#1779; &#1776;&#1785;:&#1780;&#1785;:&#1780;&#1783;</td>
                <td class="blueh2">&#1777;&#1779;&#1785;&#1777;/&#1776;&#1780;/&#1779; &#1777;&#1778;:&#1777;&#1785;:&#1780;&#1776;</td>
                <td class="greenh2">2.5</td>
                <td class="greenh2">2.5</td>
                <td class="purpleh2">6.75MB</td>
                <td class="purpleh2">54.13MB</td>
                <td class="purpleh2">60.87MB</td>
                <td class="purpleh2">60.87MB</td>
            </tr>
```

CSS changes:

```
#table_box tr:nth-child(odd) td { background-color:#ffffff } /*odd*/
#table_box tr:nth-child(even) td.greenh2 { background-color:#f00} /* even*/
#table_box tr:nth-child(even) td.blueh2 { background-color:#0f0} /* even*/
#table_box tr:nth-child(even) td.purpleh2 { background-color:#00f} /* even*/
#table_box tr:hover td { background-color:#fffbae; } /* hovering */

th.grey{
color:#7c7c7c!important;
}
th.blueh{
background-color:#174797;
color:#FFF!important;
}
th.blueh2{
background-color:#5492cf;
color:#FFF!important;
padding:3px!important;
}
th.greenh{
background-color:#579f0f;
color:#FFF!important;
}
th.greenh2{
background-color:#a4dd4f;
color:#FFF!important;
padding:3px!important;
}
th.purpleh{
background-color:#8e04ca;
color:#FFF!important;
}
th.purpleh2{
background-color:#d984fd;
color:#FFF!important;
padding:3px!important;
}
```

You'll need to tweak it some more to fit your desired output, but I guess the general idea is clear.
You could also do it with plain CSS without changing your HTML code if you want:

```
#table_box tr:nth-child(odd) td { background-color:#ffffff } /*odd*/
#table_box tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(1) { background-color:#f00} /* even*/
#table_box tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(2) { background-color:#0f0} /* even*/
#table_box tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(3) { background-color:#00f} /* even*/
#table_box tr:hover td { background-color:#fffbae; } /* hovering */
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks pharaoh , now work but hover don't work on multicolor even rows, what do I do for thats ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [`<colgroup>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp) tag.